# ChangePassword control

Tags: asp.net, controls, styling

I'm using the ChangePassword ASP.NET control.

As expected, when one of the requirements are not met (min password length, confirmation password doesn't match, password strength not good enough...) there are errors messages that come up in red.

[image: Concatenated error messages = BAD]

When there is more than one error, they seem to just concatenate on one single line. This looks ugly, and cluttered.

What can I do so that when there are 2 or more errors, each will be on its own line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies.

It turns out that my ChangePasswordFailureText was set exactly to:

> Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: {0}. Non-alphanumeric characters required: {1}.

There's no way this could have been seperated.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the [`ChangePassword.FailureTextStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.failuretextstyle.aspx) property.

> Gets a reference to a collection of Style properties that define the
>   appearance of error messages on the ChangePassword control.

Comment: What exactly can I change?
Any styling I apply applies to the concatenated chunk...


`<td align="center" style="color:Red;" colspan="2" class="chFailText">Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 6. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0.</td>`

When I add a class to the property, it just applies to everything...

Comment: @greenPerson: For example the `CssClass` property which should allow you to control the layout completely. If that doesn't work build a custom `ChangePasswordTemplate`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.changepasswordtemplate.aspx